# Unable to attach java sources to APK being debugged in Android Studio -- Option not displayed

Tags: debugging, android, apk

This article (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger) explains how to debug third-party APKs and set breakpoints by attaching the java source (you can use decompiled code to get it mostly working). Other tutorials online likewise give the same instruction, which is to open the smali file in Android studio, and when presented with the banner saying to attach Java sources, click the link in the banner to attach them. The problem is when I do this myself, there is no link in the banner. I've tried context menus, scouring the toolbar, searching online, but no one mentions what to do in this situation. I can't find another method of attaching them except from this one place, so there's no fallback.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Late to write. Same mistake i have done here. You should point that java class located folder instead of the java file.